# Extract parameters of CSR request from certificate (public key)

Tags: openssl, x509, pki

Is it possible to extract values used during creation of CSR (for example using openssl)?

In other words does public key (.crt file) contain the following data:
C=?, ST=?, L=?, O=?, OU=?, CN=?, name=?, emailAddress=?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openssl req -in request.csr -text -noout` will print a textual version of the request, e.g.

```
$ openssl req -in bigexponent.csr -text -noout
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=.NET Framework (CoreFX), CN=localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:81:c1:cb:d8:20:3f:62:4a:53:9e:d6:60:81:
                    75:37:23:93:a2:83:7d:48:90:e4:8a:19:de:d3:69:
                    73:11:56:20:96:8d:6b:e0:d3:da:a3:8a:a7:77:be:
                    02:ee:0b:6b:93:b7:24:e8:dc:c1:2b:63:2b:4f:a8:
                    0b:bc:92:5b:ce:62:4f:4c:a7:cc:60:63:06:b3:94:
                    03:e2:8c:93:2d:24:dd:54:6f:fe:4e:f6:a3:7f:10:
                    77:0b:22:15:ea:8c:bb:5b:f4:27:e8:c4:d8:9b:79:
                    eb:33:83:75:10:0c:5f:83:e5:5d:e9:b4:46:6d:df:
                    be:ee:42:53:9a:ef:33:ef:18:7b:77:60:c3:b1:a1:
                    b2:10:3c:2d:81:44:56:4a:0c:10:39:a0:9c:85:cf:
                    6b:59:74:eb:51:6f:c8:d6:62:3c:94:ae:3a:5a:0b:
                    b3:b4:c7:92:95:7d:43:23:91:56:6c:f3:e2:a5:2a:
                    fb:0c:14:2b:9e:06:81:b8:97:26:71:af:2b:82:dd:
                    39:0a:39:b9:39:cf:71:95:68:68:7e:49:90:a6:30:
                    50:ca:77:68:dc:d6:b3:78:84:2f:18:fd:b1:f6:d9:
                    ff:09:6b:af:7b:eb:98:dc:f9:30:d6:6f:cf:d5:03:
                    f5:8d:41:bf:f4:62:12:e2:4e:3a:fc:45:ea:42:bd:
                    88:47
                Exponent: 8589935681 (0x200000441)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, DNS:localhost
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         3b:ca:e7:e0:2d:3a:82:84:35:11:0c:8a:65:19:7f:f1:a0:27:
         ec:5a:ca:37:eb:e2:9b:6e:70:93:a4:bd:ca:9b:da:8e:24:4d:
         c0:58:46:aa:9f:18:6d:2e:bb:df:64:74:bb:09:ec:f5:a3:c1:
         1f:3a:7e:56:d9:d4:89:c3:d4:ae:2d:cf:5d:52:ab:fc:df:ed:
         6d:46:23:af:7c:7d:2e:52:a1:89:bc:4a:0b:fc:5e:b9:6e:c1:
         58:a9:6b:29:2d:f6:e4:ad:ca:e5:23:3a:7e:15:98:44:4e:23:
         f7:32:52:6b:71:17:22:66:e4:57:06:f9:0e:fa:b0:94:5a:75:
         d4:46:f0:a6:54:7c:78:8d:d8:1a:d6:f4:d1:e7:fd:0e:88:84:
         08:3a:f5:20:03:d9:cd:38:b3:a1:40:f2:e5:52:cf:3f:bf:0b:
         4c:77:1e:57:45:c6:da:6f:26:dc:fd:0f:eb:87:b9:fd:d2:f4:
         72:4a:09:de:1f:b4:c5:5e:43:9f:43:c6:e3:7a:86:6b:a1:94:
         94:b2:10:d2:94:69:9b:3c:95:7c:6d:d2:2e:9b:63:db:ae:3b:
         5a:e6:29:19:f0:ea:3d:f3:04:c7:dd:9e:0b:ba:0e:70:53:60:
         5f:d0:66:a7:88:42:61:59:bb:93:7c:58:e5:a1:10:46:1d:c9:
         36:4c:a7:ca
```

If you just want the request subject that is obtainable by something like

```
$ openssl req -in bigexponent.csr -noout -subject
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=.NET Framework (CoreFX)/CN=localhost
```

For anything more specific than that you'll need to parse the text, or switch to a programmatic model.

Similarly, if you are wanting the data from the assigned certificate you would use the `openssl x509` command.  But beware that an issued certificate doesn't really have to have anything in common with the certificate request (the public key will be the same, unless the CA gave you a new private key with the new certificate... but that's not common (and "not good")).

```
$ openssl x509 -in bigexponent.cer -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 11195357966677484939 (0x9b5de6c15126a58b)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=.NET Framework (CoreFX), CN=localhost
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  2 01:48:00 2016 GMT
            Not After : Mar  2 01:48:00 2017 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=.NET Framework (CoreFX), CN=localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:81:c1:cb:d8:20:3f:62:4a:53:9e:d6:60:81:
                    75:37:23:93:a2:83:7d:48:90:e4:8a:19:de:d3:69:
                    73:11:56:20:96:8d:6b:e0:d3:da:a3:8a:a7:77:be:
                    02:ee:0b:6b:93:b7:24:e8:dc:c1:2b:63:2b:4f:a8:
                    0b:bc:92:5b:ce:62:4f:4c:a7:cc:60:63:06:b3:94:
                    03:e2:8c:93:2d:24:dd:54:6f:fe:4e:f6:a3:7f:10:
                    77:0b:22:15:ea:8c:bb:5b:f4:27:e8:c4:d8:9b:79:
                    eb:33:83:75:10:0c:5f:83:e5:5d:e9:b4:46:6d:df:
                    be:ee:42:53:9a:ef:33:ef:18:7b:77:60:c3:b1:a1:
                    b2:10:3c:2d:81:44:56:4a:0c:10:39:a0:9c:85:cf:
                    6b:59:74:eb:51:6f:c8:d6:62:3c:94:ae:3a:5a:0b:
                    b3:b4:c7:92:95:7d:43:23:91:56:6c:f3:e2:a5:2a:
                    fb:0c:14:2b:9e:06:81:b8:97:26:71:af:2b:82:dd:
                    39:0a:39:b9:39:cf:71:95:68:68:7e:49:90:a6:30:
                    50:ca:77:68:dc:d6:b3:78:84:2f:18:fd:b1:f6:d9:
                    ff:09:6b:af:7b:eb:98:dc:f9:30:d6:6f:cf:d5:03:
                    f5:8d:41:bf:f4:62:12:e2:4e:3a:fc:45:ea:42:bd:
                    88:47
                Exponent: 8589935681 (0x200000441)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                78:A5:C7:5D:51:66:73:31:D5:A9:69:24:11:4C:9B:5F:A0:0D:7B:CB
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:78:A5:C7:5D:51:66:73:31:D5:A9:69:24:11:4C:9B:5F:A0:0D:7B:CB

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         77:75:6d:05:ff:a6:ad:fe:d5:b6:d4:af:b5:40:84:0c:6d:01:
         cf:6b:3f:a6:c9:73:df:d6:1f:ca:a0:a8:14:fa:1e:24:69:01:
         9d:94:b1:d8:56:d0:7d:d2:b9:5b:85:50:df:d2:08:59:53:a4:
         94:b9:9e:fc:ba:a7:98:2c:e7:71:98:4f:9d:4a:44:5f:fe:e0:
         62:e8:a0:49:73:6a:39:fd:99:4e:1f:da:0a:5d:c2:b5:b0:e5:
         7a:0b:10:c4:1b:c7:fe:6a:40:b2:4f:85:97:73:02:59:3e:60:
         b9:8d:d4:81:1d:47:d9:48:ed:f8:d6:e6:b5:af:80:a1:82:74:
         96:e2:0b:fd:24:0e:46:76:74:50:4d:4e:47:03:33:1d:64:70:
         5c:36:fb:6e:14:ba:bf:d9:cb:ee:c4:4b:33:a8:d7:b3:64:79:
         90:0f:3c:5b:ba:b6:9c:5e:45:3d:18:07:83:e2:50:80:51:b9:
         98:c0:38:e4:62:25:71:d2:ab:89:1d:89:8e:54:58:82:8c:f1:
         86:79:51:7d:28:db:ca:bf:72:e8:13:07:bf:d7:21:b7:3d:db:
         17:51:12:3f:99:d8:fc:0d:53:37:98:c4:db:d1:47:19:d5:d8:
         a8:5b:00:a1:44:a3:67:67:7b:48:89:1a:9b:56:f0:45:33:48:
         11:ba:cb:7a
```

(If you get an error like `Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` then your certificate is encoded as binary, when OpenSSL expected PEM; so add `-inform der`)

Comment: You extracted data from CSR, but I told about CRT file (issued certificate). Let's say we used some info in CSR and then it is reflected in some way in CRT file. Is it possible to get such data from CRT not from CSR (for example original CSR is absent).

Comment: `openssl x509 -in foo.cer -text -noout`. (`-inform der` if needed). The CSR and the cert have fairly little to do with each other, a CA can replace pretty much anything in the request (except the public key... unless they give you your new private key with the cert)

Comment: Please update your reply with information from your comment. It is exactly what I needed as answer. And I can say in my case CA stores all info into certificate and I have successfully extracted issuer and subject.

Comment: @Maxim There you go.